# Object is null while POSTING data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In MY MVC5 application i created a view based on this model

```
Public int Id {get;set;}
Public int Name{get;set;}
Public int Ppt1{get;set;}
Public int Ppt2{get;set;}
Public MYClass2 Obj1 {get;set;} // These   objects properties are displayed in view ( Not used for editting)
Public MyClass3 Obj2 {get;set;}
```

And my Action methods in controllers are

```
public ActionResult Create(int Project, int Licensee)
{
  MyModel obj=new MyModel();
  obj.Obj1=;//set the object
  obj.Obj2=;//set the object
  return view(obj);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int Project, int Licensee,BorrowedTextItem model)
{
  //Here Values of Oj1 and Obj2 are null.? ANy idea why?
}
```

Any idea why values of obj1 and obj2 are null while posting data?

Comment: can you add the form inside the view responsible of posting the data

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GZxcdf3t Pleasec heck on this link

Comment: Use `HiddenFor` to persists the Obj1 and Obj2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why values of obj1 and obj2 are null while posting data?

You are only displaying the values of those fields using `Html.DisplayFor`. There are no corresponding input fields. So they will never be sent to the server.

You might need to add corresponding hidden fields so that the values are sent to the server when the form is submitted:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => mode.Obj1.Foo)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => mode.Obj1.Bar)
...
```

Or even better, since those values are not supposed to be modified by the user, it would be far better to retrieve them from your backend when the form is submitted. In the GET action you retrieved their corresponding values from somewhere. In your POST action simply retrieve them from the same place.

Comment: I agreed on this . But is that a good way in terms of perfomance ( fetching again while POSTing the data)